# Full page Cache cannot catch all pages

Tags: full-page-cache, ce-1.9.2.2, redis

I have Magento 1.9.2.2

I was using mirasvit full page cache, now I am using potato full page cache.

My server VDS, 8CPU, 16GB RAM

Now I am using seperated redis servers for 1-sessions and 2-cache+fpc. I also tried via 3 seperated redis server. 
1- Sessions
2- Magento Cache
3- Full Page Cache

It is working but after website fully cached, FPC is missing %30 of cached pages. This problem was same at mirasvit. What is the problem? Is this normal as a cache logic? After nearly website fully cached website is going slower.

Second question about Redis cleanup..
Should I use Scheduled Redis cache clean up. I tried to clean via redis-cli.php but I couldnt see any cahnge at key size.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your FPC settings.
but fully cached site (even with holepunches) must work very fast.
it is hard to say what exactly you have in admin configuration.

you must open a ticket with cache extension developers. usually they check settings and fix any issues.

also they will provide you with garbage cleaner.